# cannot import npm installed modules (lightweight-charts)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, lightweight-charts

I'm new to the world of JS and recently trying to write a toy app using [lightweight-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightweight-charts). I've gone through several tutorials and learned some basic concepts. But I'm so mad at myself that I still cannot figure out in what context can I use the 'es6 via npm' example mentioned in the lightweight-chart NPM page above. The CDN example seems to be fine, though.

Here is what I did

1. install lightweight-charts locally. - `npm install lightweight-charts`
2. create a `test.mjs` in the same directory, which contains only one lines.

```js
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';
```

3. run the code.
   `node test.mjs`

But I got the following errors

> SyntaxError: Named export 'createChart' not found. The requested module 'lightweight-charts' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.

It does not make sense for me because the official npm site says es6 supported, but the error messages seem to indicate that this module is for CommonJS. Even after I
rewrote this in CommonJS style using 'require' syntax and rename "test.mjs" to "test.js", some dependency modules are still using 'import' syntax and caused some so
rt of "cannot use import statement outside a module" errors.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen with `node test.mjs`? `lightweight-charts` is a package for charts in HTML. It doesn't make sense to use this package in Node.js. You need a browser environment to use this package

Comment: @jabaa oh yes I get your point, I just tried to run through that import line to see whether it will go through without any errors. I did something like using an index.html to have a JS file in the <script> tag, but when I tried that import line in the JS file it threw "cannot use import statement outside a module" error.

Comment: @jabaa I am so confused since the npm site says you can use that import syntax (and this is within the context of Node.js if I understand correctly), but as you pointed out this should be used in a browser environment, so I just wonder in what kinda situation I'm gonna use that "import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';" line.

Comment: You use this syntax with module loaders or bundlers. Or you can use a valid Internet URL and import this module as a ES6 module. You can read about [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). There are multiple different ways to import a module into your frontend JavaScript code.

Comment: @jabaa correct me if I'm wrong, when using the external URL, there is nothing to do with the locally installed npm modules? (i.e., those in the node_modules/)

Comment: Your webserver can deliver the packages from `node_modules`, and browsers can access the packages. That's how many people handled this before bundlers were a thing. You could use a path like `yourdomain.com/scripts/lightweight-charts.js`. CDN in production can be very dangerous. Someone could hack a CDN and replace the modules with malicious software.

Comment: @jabaa yes that's kind of the picture I thought of. I was thinking maybe I should import lightweight-charts from the node_modules first then pass it to the browser somehow. So that's why I tried that line and get that error. To avoid extended discussions in comments would you offer an simple example using that import line, if possible.

Comment: There is no simple import line. You have to configure your webserver or build system.

Answer (score 0):

This package is not meant to be executed on the backend with NodeJS. It will only work in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I really hate to ask this way but could you give me a minimal example of how to import the npm installed module in the browser environment.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to install Babel compiler [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/)